# Identifying similar font to Futura

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

Today I watched a Ted Talk, and loved the presentation. In particular the font used.

I did some research and found out this looked like Futura. So I did compare the two, but there are *subtle differences*. See the image below.

I went through the most similar Futura fonts on [myfonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/futura/all/), but can't find the exact one. Anyone an idea **what font/ Futura edition this might be**?

Note:

- how the `O` is square even though this is italic
- the significance width difference of the `D`, `C` and `W`
- the lower ending of the stem of the `J` is tapered off

[image: comparison]

(The Ted Talk: We can reprogram life. How to do it wisely | Juan Enriquez)

Comment: Worth noting that the same font is used throughout the talk in various slides, so there may be better letters for comparison.

Comment: Futura is one of those fonts that can be a bit of a pain sometimes.  Like Helvetica, it seems like there are a million different versions floating around and no one uses the same.  Because of this, I have a bunch of different Futuras on my system.  I couldn't find an exact match for this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a comparison of `Twentieth Century Pro Bold Italic`, that Mvp Web Pro suggested. And turns out they are quite close, but not an exact match.

[image: comparison of Twentieth Century Pro Bold Italic and screengrab]

Since my initial comparison of `Futura LT HeavyOblique` and the screengrab and this one are that close, I'll answer my own question and close the question.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

I checked your screen capture out on http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/
When I used all the recognizable characters, it didn't find a match, but when I used only the "J", it found it right away.

Try - Twentieth Century Pro Bold Italic
Looks like a match to me, using the "playbox" on http://www.fonthaus.com/fonts/monotypeimaging/Twentieth-Century/MI167349586

I just noticed your first example "LIFECODE" and the "E", "F" and "C" do not seem to match up.  Not sure if this is a different Font, or a variant.

Perhaps Twentieth Century Medium Italic with a Bold Added.  The distinguishing question mark matches.

A screenshot of Twentieth Century Pro Bold Italic on Fonthaus:
[image: Twentieth Century Pro Bold Italic]